# How Might I Convert This C# Code In To Batch File Code?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have read that Win32 will not allow remote invocation of a process that is interactive and I suspect a Console Application is considered to be interactive by Windows and so instead, if I could convert the following code in to a batch file then I am hoping I can remotely run the batch file on the server computer from a client. Feel free to correct this logic if I'm wrong.

The code is:

```
namespace PRIMEWebFlyControl
{
  class Program
  {

    // name of the process we will retrieve a handle to
    private const string PROCESS_NAME = "PRIMEPipeLine";
    private static Process ProgramHandle;
    private static string command;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("This program has been launched remotely!");
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\PRIMEWeb\\Executables\\FlyCommand.txt");
        command = tr.ReadLine();
        tr.Close();

        ExecuteCommand();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr handle);

    private static void ExecuteCommand() {
        if (AssignProcessHandle()) {
            IntPtr p = ProgramHandle.MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(p);
            SendKeys.SendWait(command + "~"); // "~" is equivalent to pressing Enter
        }
    }



    private static bool AssignProcessHandle()
    {
        // ask the system for all processes that match the name we are looking for
        Process[] matchingProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(PROCESS_NAME);
        // if none are returned then we haven't found the program so return false;
        if (matchingProcesses.Length == 0) return false;
        // else, set our reference to the running program
        ProgramHandle = matchingProcesses[0];

        // return true to indicate we have assigned the ref sucessfully
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

As you will notice the code contains method calls of Windows library methods like SetForegroundWindow() and as I am unfamiliar with batch files, I wondered how the same thing might be achieved.

Many thanks

Comment: You trying to transmit command to some specific application? One of possible solutions is to run small server application with your provided code, which accepts remote command and repeats them locally. This can be done by using Remoting or WCF (hosted in win application).

Comment: another thing to try is psexec.  Also, powershell has a means of remotely executing stuff, but it is far more twisted than psexc's

Comment: What I have is an ASP page which is linked to a WCF Service. The program that I want to pass the sent keys to is always running on the server computer, so I built a second lightweight console app to be launched by the WCF Service that comprises of just the code shown above which finds the running process and sends keys to it before exiting itself. Having run tests the ASP page reports a successful execution but on my server computer the program isnt visible (even when letting the console wait for input and not close). So I am trying to find a solution, though now batch doesnt seem the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you are looking for a command line that will execute a bunch of commands that exist inside a text file named (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PRIMEWeb\Executables\FlyCommand.txt)

Here is what you need to do:

```
cmd < C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PRIMEWeb\Executables\FlyCommand.txt
```

In case the path contains spaces, use the following command:

```
cmd < "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PRIMEWeb\Executables\FlyCommand.txt"
```